# Prosody XMPP server isn't receiving files, returns 404

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, prosody-im

I'm setting up my own XMPP server on a VPS, mostly for additional control and not for public use. I want to set up HTTP file upload, using an "upload." subdomain. However, attempting to send files gives me a 404. I'm using prosody-filer.